# How can I send a message to a discord webhook through a browser console

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make code that can send a message to a discord webhook through a browser console but I can't get it to work

I tried this, as well as some reddit threads and reading the docs

Edit: I also tried using a referrer and origin header with no success

```
fetch('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/WEBHOOK_ID/WEBHOOK_TOKEN', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    content: 'hello world'
  })
});
```

I'm getting a POST 400 error but i cant for the life of me figure out why
(Yes im using an actual URL when i try the code)

```
POST https://discord.com/api/webhooks/[ID/TOKEN] 400
(anonymous) @ 00a5b07b3b8bf783d65a.js:153
(anonymous) @ VM234:1

{"message": "Invalid request origin", "code": 50067}
```

Comment: What is the response body when you receive an HTTP 400 status code?

Comment: I tried this locally (with my own webhook URL) and it worked. What is the actual message you're sending? I suspect that's the issue.

Comment: Please append the 400 error massage to make the question easy to answer

Comment: @emeraldsanto I added the error to the post

Comment: @asportnoy I'm literally trying to send hello world at this point
What browser were you using? maybe thats the issue?

Comment: @powerhouse222 please include the request body, not whatever is in the devtools console. Thats what will actually tell us what the issue is.

Comment: @asportnoy sorry I'm a bit slow I'll append it to the post now

Comment: Whatever website you are making the request from is blocked by Discord, possibly due to a history of abuse or some other issue. Making the request from another site or from a server should fix the issue.

Comment: @asportnoy I'm making the request from discord though

Comment: Yep, looks like that's the issue. Not exactly sure why but I'd guess there is some security-related reason to block webhook requests from their own site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord doesn't allow webhook requests from their own site for security reasons
My best guess is that they dont want people to be able to send discord cookies with a webhook

Answer (score 1):

You can always check this website for help

https://discohook.org/

For example I tried one and checked the network request that was fired upon the webhook send was something like this.

So maybe `embeds:null` and `attachments:[]` is required in the body

```js
fetch("https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/id/token", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-language": "en",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"111\", \"Not(A:Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"111\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Linux\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin"
  },
  "body": "{\"content\":\"This is a webhook message from the browser\",\"embeds\":null,\"attachments\":[]}",
  "method": "POST"
});
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if that worked for you